# getaccesstoken auth scheme name provided but says it isn't

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, blazor, openid-connect

in a Blazor component I would like to call my API which is hosted in the same application for now. This used to work until I added authentication and authorization. Calling the API from my browser works fine. when I try to call the same API the returned response content is the HTML for the Microsoft OIDC login.

When I try to get the user access token to pass as a bearer token I get an error that says
`System.InvalidOperationException: IDW10503: Cannot determine the cloud Instance. The provided authentication scheme was 'MicrosoftOidc'. Microsoft.Identity.Web inferred 'MicrosoftOidc' as the authentication scheme. Available authentication schemes are 'MicrosoftOidc,Bearer,Cookies,OpenIdConnect'. See https://aka.ms/id-web/authSchemes.`

So it says the provided authentication scheme was MicrosoftOidc, was inferred as MicrosoftOidc, and that available schemes include Microsoft Oidc. My user logs in and gets the roles assigned just fine. I get this error on this line `var token = await tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new[] { "Spec.Read" }, authenticationScheme: "MicrosoftOidc");`

here is how I set up authentication in my program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("MicrosoftOidc")
    .AddOpenIdConnect("MicrosoftOidc", oidcOptions =>
    {
        oidcOptions.Scope.Add(OpenIdConnectScope.OfflineAccess);
        oidcOptions.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        oidcOptions.SaveTokens = true;
        oidcOptions.Authority = builder.Configuration["AzureAd:Instance"];
        oidcOptions.ClientId = builder.Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
        oidcOptions.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["AzureAd:ClientSecret"];
        oidcOptions.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
        oidcOptions.MapInboundClaims = false;
        oidcOptions.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Name;
        oidcOptions.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "roles";
        oidcOptions.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerValidator = AadIssuerValidator.GetAadIssuerValidator(
            oidcOptions.Authority,
            oidcOptions.Backchannel).Validate;
    }).AddJwtBearer()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration)
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(builder.Configuration.GetValue<string[]>("DownstreamApi:Scopes"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

var map = JsonWebTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap;

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();

builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddMvcOptions(options=>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
}).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

builder.Services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedHost;

    options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
    options.KnownProxies.Clear();

    options.AllowedHosts = builder.Configuration.GetSection("AllowedHosts").Get<List<string>>();
});

builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddControllers();

...
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRewriter(
    new RewriteOptions().Add(context =>
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.Request.Path == "/signout-oidc")
            context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("https://Corrugated.io");
    }));

app.UseForwardedHeaders();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.MapControllers();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

here's the relative app settings

```
{
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/",
  "TenantId": "be664a41-9b40-4c81-b11e-e52879b29fe9",
  "ClientId": "f75fae40-5787-48f4-8834-7354c224e530",
  "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
  "ClientSecret": "super secret"
},

"DownstreamApi": {
  "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
  "RelativePath": "me",
  "Scopes": [
    "user.read"
  ]
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? going to the linked aka site doesn't really help me out as it's configuring the auth in a little different way, but not by much, basically just passing in defaults.

Also I may be trying to call the API in a wrong way. One of my other components under the hood is doing a js interop call to another one of my API controllers and is authenticated correctly. Should I just do that? I would think that passing in a bearer token would be more correct. especially if I'm going to try and break out the API later.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'm not very sure about `my API which is hosted in the same application`, because we can see we have `builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();` in `Program.cs` so that this is a blazor server app with .net 8 **(**.net 8 using blazor web app to replace blazor server so I'm afraid you are migrating your old blazor server app to .net 8 but don't like to use blazor web app feature, but this is not important for this issue **)**. Therefore, we are now having an app which have UI and the UI is rendered in the server side, and we have API exposed in the same project. And now we also call the API in the project. This confused me.

Let's go back to your code and error. First of all, we are now [using MSAL library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/msal-migration) for Microsoft authentication. Therefore, we shall use `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication` or `builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp` instead of `AddAuthentication("MicrosoftOidc").AddOpenIdConnect()` in the blazor server app. Here we have [some official samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/sample-v2-code?tabs=apptype#web-applications) for different scenario.

Then I noticed that you have `"BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",` in your appsettings.json, so I'm afraid you are trying to call MS Graph API within your blazor server app, then the steps should be 1. sign into your app with MS account -> 2. generate access token via tokenAcquisition -> 3. call API url to get response or 2. using Graph SDK to call Graph API and get response. The error you got means there's something wrong with the authentication. I will show you a sample I test in my side.

Program.cs

```
using BlazorServerGraph5.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();


builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

var app = builder.Build();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
app.Run();
```

FetchData.razor

```
@page "/fetchdata"
@using BlazorServerGraph5.Data
@inject WeatherForecastService ForecastService
@using Microsoft.Graph
@using Microsoft.Graph.Models
@inject GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient

<PageTitle>Weather forecast</PageTitle>
<h1>Weather forecast</h1>
<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from a service.</p>

@if (forecasts == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Temp. (C)</th>
                <th>Temp. (F)</th>
                <th>Summary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var forecast in forecasts)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@forecast.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureC</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureF</td>
                    <td>@forecast.Summary</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@code {
    private WeatherForecast[]? forecasts;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var me = await graphServiceClient.Me.GetAsync();
        forecasts = await ForecastService.GetForecastAsync(DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now));
    }
}
```

appsettings.json

```
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "Domain": "tenant_id",
  "TenantId": "tenant_id",
  "ClientId": "client_id",
  "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
  "ClientSecret": "client_secret"//authentication Graph SDK requires client secret
},
"DownstreamApi": {
  "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
  "Scopes": "User.ReadWrite.All"
},
```

nuget packages

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="7.0.13" NoWarn="NU1605" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="7.0.13" NoWarn="NU1605" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="5.40.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph.Core" Version="3.1.6" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="2.16.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClient" Version="2.16.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="2.16.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

create a Login partial component

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        Hello, @context.User.Identity?.Name!
        <a href="MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignOut">Log out</a>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <a href="MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn">Log in</a>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

and put it in MainLayout

```
<div class="top-row px-4 auth">
    <LoginDisplay />
    <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
</div>
```

In App.razor, surround the  with `<CascadingAuthenticationState>`

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. When i'm trying to implement your solution, the `.AddMicrosoftGraph` line doesn't exist when trying to add authentication. I have all the same using statements minus the `blazorservergraph5.data`. is there a nuget package I need to install?

Comment: Hi, `AddMicrosoftGraph ` belongs to nuget package `namespace Microsoft.Identity.Web;` Could you please help clean the project and rebuild the app to see whether the error still existed? By the way, could you please help check your nuget packages and mine, to see whether these's any conflict in packages and version?